# Individual tag badge descriptions are incorrect

Tags: bug, tag-badges

The individual tag badge descriptions[(1)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/803/mathematica?userid=618728)[(2)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1079/mathematica?userid=618728)[(3)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1411/mathematica?userid=618728) are all stating **80** as the minimum number of answers:

[image]

This is incorrect.  **80** is only the minimum for the silver badge, as shown on the [badge overview page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges):

> Bronze Badge  You must have a total score of 100 in at least **20**
>   non-community wiki answers to achieve this badge.
>   50.3k awarded
>
> Silver Badge You must have a total score of 400 in at least **80**
>   non-community wiki answers to achieve this badge.
>   9.1k awarded
>
> Gold Badge You must have a total score of 1000 in at least **200**
>   non-community wiki answers to achieve this badge.
>   2.7k awarded

This affects Stack Overflow as well as other sites such as [Mathematica](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @JoshC This isn't (just) the tooltips, as my included image shows.

Comment: I guess. But the other question does seem to address this, though the title may not.

Comment: This doesn't occur for me on the main overview page - only on the [tag badges page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges?tab=tags).

Comment: @Bart now that *does* appear to be a duplicate.

Comment: We'll do whatever it takes to close this @Mr.Wizard. MUWAHAHAHAha...ahem.... ;)

Comment: @Bart I have voted to close this myself.  I'm not upset.

Comment: @animuson same here; I am using the overview as a reference for what these *should* read.